# Enable SAXParser qName to handle spaces

Tags: java, sax, saxparser

I am having a little trouble with my XML parser, effectively I have an XML structure like so:

```
<c r="K6" s="35">
  <v>135</v> 
</c>
```

& I need to extract the value **v XXX /v** dependent on whether **c r="K6" s="35"** falls within a specific range. This is simple enough using reg ex's etc... but my issue is that when I pull down the qName in `startElement()`, rather than returning the value: `c r="K6" s="35"` its simply returns: `c`. I am 99% sure this is because qName breaks at the first space. How can I get qName to return everything within the <> brackets?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML tags cannot contain spaces. What you have in your XML element is

- A tag called `c`,
- ...that has an *attribute* called `r` with the value `K6`,
- ...and another attribute called `s` with the value `35`.

`SAXParser` already returns the values of all attributes to you in the attribute list that you get along with the element that has its `qName` set to `"c"`.

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) {
    if ("c".equals(qName)) {
        System.out.println(attributes.getValue("r"));
    }
}
```